# Does PHP SVM support mutli classes?

Tags: php, classification, svm, libsvm

The example at http://php.net/manual/en/svm.examples.php shows only two classes: 1 or -1 . Can there be more? I read that it can be done directly via libsvm as explained here [MultiClass using LIBSVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979531/multiclass-using-libsvm)